# Access Apple's Memoji Keyboard in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Trying to see if it's possible to access Apple's Memoji keyboard in React Native. I read somewhere that other applications simply paste the output from the keyboard as an Image, and I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow get access to that Memoji image in React Native.

See that attached image for an example of the specific emoji keyboard I am referring to. [Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4eZg.jpg). Thanks for your help!